# What is the simplest EWS call to test connectivity?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Among all the [Exchange Web Services Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/bb409286%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) I'm looking for the simplest one I can initially use to check if my connectivity to the EWS endpoint works.
The low-level code I use to build and execute SOAP calls expects valid results so whatever operation I use should not return with an error message.

I have considered several but don't find them satisfactory:

- [GetServerTimeZones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd899430%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) is only supported from Exchange 2010, and I need 2007+
- [ResolveNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa563518%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) needs a (partial) user name, but I want it do to be user independent. Also, it could return errors (not match) or maybe hundreds of matches (match with 'e').
- [GetUserConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd899439%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) works for the currently logged in user, but is only supported from 2010.

Any other ideas?

Comment: You could just open an HTTPS connection to the given EWS endpoint. That at least tells you that someone is listening on the other end, and will work with all versions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have decided to use ResolveNames - further processing needs a user anyway.

This gives me the opportunity to do several checks at once: general connectivity, user exists, exchange server version, etc.

EDITED 2 Aug 2013

I have switched to using [FindFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa563918%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx), this has further simplified my code.
This changes the check 'user exists' to the check 'default calendar folder exists', which the app assumes.

There is another assumption in the code, namely that time zone `W. Europe Standard Time` exists, but as my original question stated, I can only verify that for Exchange 2010 and later.

UPDATE 27 dec 2022

FindFolder lists the subfolders and we don't do anything with that information. We switched to [GetFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2007/aa580274(v=exchg.80)).

Comment: Be careful with ResolveNames. This can be an expensive call with a very large AD.