# Is DistinguishedFolderId 'inbox' guaranteed to exist?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

In Exchange Web Services we used to check connectivity by looking for the 'calendar' [DistinguishedFolderId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/distinguishedfolderid?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for the logged in user:
[What is the simplest EWS call to test connectivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566530/what-is-the-simplest-ews-call-to-test-connectivity).

Our synchronization codes relies on calendars being shared with that logged in user (delegate access).

We found out that the logged in user does not necessarily have a 'calendar' DistinguishedFolderId. It looks like admins sometimes forget to create a calendar for that user (?). For the synchronization this is not an issue, because nothing needs to be accessed in that users calendar. But the connectivity test fails because of this.

I have now switched to quering DistinguishedFolderId 'inbox' using [GetFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2007/aa580274(v=exchg.80)) for the connectivity test (and still look up 'calendar' for all the users that need to have their calendars synced).

But this brings up the question:
**Is DistinguishedFolderId 'inbox' guaranteed to exist for an Exchange user?**

We are talking about Windows AD users.

Answer (score 0):

Default folders, such as the `Inbox` folder, can't be deleted.

Comment: The question is more/wider: if an Exchange account is set up for that 'shared user',  will that folder ID exist.

Comment: Why do you need a shared Inbox folder?

Comment: I don't. The *calendars* are shared. At the time we chose for that instead of impersonation because that seemed easier with EWS. Legacy code.